# Как получить доступ к аудио файлу по Uri android?

Tags: java, android, uri, android-mediaplayer

Приложение плеер для android. 
С помощью интента Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT пользователь находит в памяти телефона аудиофайл. После этого запоминается Uri аудиофайла: `data.getData()`
Когда надо проиграть файл, создаётся Mediaplayer:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),sourceUri);
player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

Всё хорошо создаётся, проигрывается, работает. При закрытии программы Uri сохраняется в бд с помощью `sourceUri.toString();`. При повторном открытии пути загружаются через `Uri.parse()`. Загружаются правильно, все как и были. 
 Но при попытке проиграть песню по этому Uri приложение вылетает: `MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),sourceUri);` возвращает null. Похоже, что нет прав доступа. Причём если после запуска загрузить хоть 1 песню из памяти (новую, старую не важно), то все Uri, загруженные из бд начинают "работать" и прав им уже хватает.
Что сделать, чтобы прав хватало при запуске сразу?

Comment: используйте ACTION_PICK

Comment: @S Спасибо. Это стало частью решения проблемы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете удержать права доступа на полученную URI так:

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
// Check for the freshest data.
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
```

Более подробно в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions).

Comment: Ух ты, а я и не знал этого, что можно удержать права - полезное знание, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Только надо было ещё заменить intent на ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Код на java: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 intent.setType("audio/*");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
 | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
 | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivityForResult(intent,1);` в части с объявлением намерения и `int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
          | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      CR.takePersistableUriPermission(URI, takeFlags);`

Answer (score 1):

Это не баг а фича. Так работает [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) - чтобы получить доступ к файлу во внешнем хранилище обязательно нужно участие юзера через `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT/ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, если функционал вашего приложения устроен так, что требуется возможность повторного прослушивания без вмешательства юзера, то надо копировать файл себе через:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```